# Wavy Gravy Record Labels

Tags: record

Who owned the record label "Wavy Gravy", what records did it put out, how long did it run for, and do the artists still receive royalties? Any info is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

[Wavy Gravy](http://www.45cat.com/label/wavy-gravy) was a bootleg/pirate label with just a scant few releases.  Being that the releases were pirates (i.e. released without the bands' knowledge or consent), it's 99.999% likely that none of the artists saw a dime from any of their releases.

Answer (score 2):

From another source, [Discogs](https://www.discogs.com/fr/label/263089-Wavy-Gravy), you can have a little more information.

### What records dit this label release?

- Eddie Noack, Porter Wagoner - *Psycho / The Rubber Room*
- Gin Gillette, Baron Daemon & The Vampires - *Train To Satanville / Ghost Guitars*
- The Shandells / The Ideals - *Gorilla*
- The Motions , Alf Newman - *Bumble Bee '65 / It's A Gas*

### Records Cat Number

If you look closely, you can see that the cat numbers on the label do not look like an official code for the label (like a serial number) but have a funny name related to the A-Side track name.

- Eddie Noack - *Psycho* : **PSYCH-0**
- Gin Gillette - *Train To Satanville* : **HELLBOUND 666**
- The Shandells  - *Gorilla* : **GRILLA 000-000**
- The Motions - *Bumble Bee '65* : **BZZ 65**

### Label time of activity

These two sources, [45cat](http://www.45cat.com/label/wavy-gravy) and [Discogs](https://www.discogs.com/fr/label/263089-Wavy-Gravy) you can find one of these records was released in 2011. I can only speculate the other records were released around the same time. But, the original tracks were released around the 60s.

### What were this tracks?

If you look closer what were these original tracks, you can find that they are highly talked and requested on the Internet. I don't know all the details, but they look rare and wanted buy some record collectors.

### Conclusion (Speculation)

I think this is a fake label that re-issued rare and wanted songs to fool collectors and sell this pirated content at a higher price. Like Johnny Bones said, the artists, especially the older ones active in the 60s, won't receive any money from these sales.